# SQL insert Or update times out if large date in loop

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, large-data

i have some data with userid and date.

Sometimes there is large datas i need to loop through and update the sql database but the database times out.

is there any better way i can do this please, sample code below.

```
foreach($time[$re->userid][$today] as $t){

                if(($re->time >= $t->in_from) && ($re->time < $t->in_to)
                    && md5($t->WorkDay."_in".$re->date) != $in){//in

                    $tble = tools::sd("{$t->WorkDay} in");
                }

                if(($re->time >= $t->out_from) && ($re->time < $t->out_to)
                    && md5($t->WorkDay."_out".$re->date) != $out){//out

                    $tble = tools::sd("{$t->WorkDay} out");

                    if($tble =='nout'){
                        $re->date2 = tools::ndate($re->date . "- 1");
                    }
                }

                if(!empty($tble)){ 
                    $q = array(
                         "id" => $re->userid
                        , "dt" => $re->date2
                        , "{$tble}" => $re->time
                    );

                    dump($q); // insert into sql
                }
            }
```

dump function:::

```
function dump($d ='')
{
    if(!empty($d)){
    end($d);  
    $tble = key($d); 
    $d['ld'] = "{$d['dt']} {$d[$tble]}";

        $r = $GLOBALS['mssqldb']->get_results("
            IF NOT EXISTS (select id,ld,dt,{$tble} from clockL 
                WHERE id = '{$d['id']}' 
                AND dt ='{$d['dt']}')
                INSERT INTO clockL (id,ld,dt,{$tble})
                VALUES ('{$d['id']}','{$d['ld']}','{$d['dt']}'
                ,'{$d[$tble]}')
            ELSE IF EXISTS (select id,{$tble} from clockL 
                WHERE id = '{$d['id']}' 
                AND dt ='{$d['dt']}'
                AND {$tble} = 'NOC'
                ) 
                update clockL SET {$tble} ='{$d[$tble]}', ld ='{$d['ld']}' WHERE id = '{$d['id']}' 
                AND dt ='{$d['dt']}' AND {$tble} ='NOC'
            ");

            //print_r($GLOBALS['mssqldb']);
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: That's a lot of conditional logic to do inside a loop.  Another approach is to put everything into a staging table and write to your main table from the staging table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of a PHP function called `set_time_limit()`? You can find the detailed documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

This can manipulate the execution time, which is 30 seconds default. If you set it to 0, eg set_time_limit(0), there will be no execution time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Do the insert/update outside of the loop. Enclose it in a transaction so that you don't get an inconsistent database state if the script dies prematurely. Using one big query is usually faster than making lots of small queries. You might also set higher values for time and memory limits, but be aware of the consequencies.

Answer (score -1):

May be looping is the reason for time out.
Because when your performing the insert/update operations in side the loop, the connection to the database will be in open state until the loop is terminated which may cause the time out problem.

Try doing the insert/update operation outside of the loop.